# How can I make custom text appear in the top of my screen?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I know about the /title command, but I'm wondering if there's a way to be able to make custom text appear at the top of my screen. I'm hoping that there is because I want to troll my friend on **Hypixel** with fake "killaura" hacks where I pretend to leave and just hit him. Is there any mod or way to do this?
I've seen a few YouTubers do this, and it looks hilarious.

Comment: Please give an example image of how it looked. And no, the maximum height of `/title` is the middle.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the /bossbar command.
[Here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/bossbar) you can see how to use it. Basically, as the name suggests, it creates a boss bar at the top of the screen, which can be modified to your needs.

Comment: I can't use commands on a server. Much less Hypixel

Comment: Then why ask if you could use commands on a server when you already know the answer?

Comment: im not asking for a command, I'm asking if anyone knows a mod or hack that does this.

Comment: @Plasmic why not just actually use a hacked client and just turn off the hacks